# Seeing many "SHOW VARIABLES" in MySQL Process List

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

Every few hours, My MySQL database (running 5.1) seems to hang and viewing the processlist shows dozens of processes running "SHOW VARIABLES". They finish instantly only to be replaced my more of these processes. After a few minutes, everything disappears and goes back to normal.

I'm using the .Net Connector and the web application is on  IIS 6. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same problem as well